# Update cell, automatically copy row to a separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet comprising of two columns (A and B) ... the first of which is just a name, the second is a number.

If I make an edit to a number in column B, I want Excel to automatically copy that entire row to a second worksheet in order to create a list of edits that I have made.

The second worksheet would then be a continually updated list of changes that I have made to the first sheet, with the latest change (a copy of the two updated columns) added to the next unused row.

I hope that a bit of VBA trickery might be able to make this happen, but require some help to make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the sheet where you have data (under the Excel Objects), e.g Sheet1

```
Option Explicit
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim copyVal As String

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = Range("A" & Target.Row & ":B" & Target.Row)

    'copy the values
    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = rng.Value

        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy
            copyVal = CStr(PrevVal)
        End With

        .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        .Offset(1, 1) = copyVal
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

PrevVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works almost perfectly. What I did notice was when it copied the row to the second sheet it wasn't the updated row but the row as it was before I updated it. Is it possible to achieve that? Again, so grateful for the help.

Comment: So you just want the new entries to be copied and not the old or previous values?

Comment: I can see a use-case for both so knowing how to adapt the code so that the new entry is copied instead of the old one would be good.

Comment: Try to delete `copyVal = CStr(PrevVal)` and `.Offset(1, 1) = copyVal`.

Comment: As a matter of interest, can this be easily adapted to include more columns? More sheets? I've tried playing around with it but didn't figure it out.

Comment: Without having tested it, try to change the defined range (set) to column c instead of b.

Comment: I revisited this and have one further question - the copy and paste starts on row 2 of sheet 2, how do I change the row (which I believe is offset by 1 at the start because it is set to offset 1 every time it pastes). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it to start at row 1 or?

Comment: Ideally, row 1 but any row if that is possible?

Comment: There is probably a better way, but I would use an `IF`-statement, so if the cell value in row 1 is empty, then paste data there otherwise (else) paste it in the next row (the current code)

Comment: I found some code to check the row number but I don't know how to implement it... I've created another answer below in order to put the code in there...

Comment: You should create another question :-)

Comment: Ok... I'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some additional code to check the row number, as per the above answer and comments.

```
Dim row_num As Long
row_num = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If row_num > 1 then row_num = row_num + 1 'Add 1 only when row number doesn't equal to 1, otherwise - 1.
```