# Update cell, copy entire row to a separate sheet in chronological order

Tags: vba, excel

I have adapted some code from this question that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686328/update-cell-automatically-copy-row-to-a-separate-sheet/40898471#40898471) to do part of what I need it to do but have some additional questions. On Sheet 1 I have multiple columns of data, let's say A to F. If any data is changed in column F, then all the columns of data for that row (including the now updated value in column F) are copied to a second sheet (Sheet 2) generating a lengthy list recording all my changes.

Here's the code I have:

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim PrevVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 6 Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim copyVal As String

        Set rng = Nothing
        Set rng = Range("A" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row)

        'copy the values
        With Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, rng.Cells.Count).Value = rng.Value

            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy
            End With

            .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    PrevVal = Target.Value
End Sub
```

---

I've already changed a few things by playing around with the code.

If I want to expand to include additional columns then I can adjust that here

```
Set rng = Range("A" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row)
```

and I can alter the "watched" column for changes by adjusting it here

```
If Target.Column = 6 Then
```

However, my questions are :

1. How do I adapt it to watch more than one column of data (say A and F)?
2. How do I adapt it to watch a specific range of rows

Additionally, the list of updated rows begins on Sheet 2 on row 2. Is it possible to position it by column/row?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The inner `With` statement is completely unnecessary - it's never referenced.

Comment: What you want is not so clear - and testing your code it isn't true that it copies the entire row. It only copies whatever is in the corresponding column A row when you change column B...

Comment: I will edit the question after playing around with some stuff.