# How to insert new row to sheet 2 automatically when a new row is inserted to sheet 1 and copy values?

Tags: excel, vba

How to do the following:
I have 2 sheets in a single Worksheet ie; Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.
Now I want to insert a new row to Sheet 1 and fill that cells and when I insert this row, I want insert the same row automatically to Sheet 2 but without some columns. I have googled and searched many forums and website but couldn't find anything to work.

Sheet 1

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2

[image: Sheet 2]

Comment: Have you searched on here for a vba method?

Comment: Look into [worksheet_change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: is there any vba sample code that I can use..? it would help me a lot.

Comment: I searched vba method but didn't help

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service, therefore it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and improve your question to get the support you want.

Comment: if you add a line, is added at the end?

Comment: I simply tried to insert reference to sheet 1. Like in sheet 2 Cell A2 =Sheet1!A2

Comment: I filled whole sheet like that. but I want more like a vba code to do the job automatically.

Comment: @TimStack Check out this link. I can see some experts do help to simple questions like I asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686328/update-cell-automatically-copy-row-to-a-separate-sheet?rq=1

Comment: Apart from whether or not this type of question has been asked before: Why would you want to duplicate your data?That is not the best data architecture. If you need a subset of your data in a different sheet, with only a few specific columns from the original data, you don't need VBA to physically copy the data from the first sheet. There are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code in Sheet 1.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Old_lines As Long, New_Lines As Long, Row_Number As Long
Dim PrNo As String, PrNa As String, R2 As String, R3 As String, R5 As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        New_Lines = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If Old_lines < New_Lines Then

            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                .Rows(Row_Number).EntireRow.Insert
                .Range("A" & Row_Number).Formula = "=Sheet1!A" & Row_Number
                .Range("B" & Row_Number).Formula = "=Sheet1!B" & Row_Number
                .Range("C" & Row_Number).Formula = "=Sheet1!D" & Row_Number
                .Range("D" & Row_Number).Formula = "=Sheet1!E" & Row_Number
                .Range("E" & Row_Number).Formula = "=Sheet1!G" & Row_Number

            End With

        End If

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Old_lines = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Row_Number = Target.Row

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: wow. this worked. thank you so much for the help. I am still learning. I am very new to these code stuffs.

Comment: I have 1 more question. I have another worksheet with many columns. If I add this code to that worksheet, will it work..?

Comment: Check both sheet names and change them.

Comment: But this code doesn't work if I use it in a Right to Left sheet. Is there any changes that I need to alter for this to work on right to left sheets

Comment: does your code work for the question and does not work for the new senario?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without any VBA. Instead of VBA to duplicate the data, use Power Query. Query the data from Sheet1 as the source. Delete the columns you don't need. Load the query result into Sheet2.

When new data is added to Sheet1, simply refresh the query by clicking Data > Refresh All.

If you want to automate it with VBA, use a Worksheet_Change event on Sheet1 that does the equivalent of Data > Refresh All. The macro recorder will show you the command you need.

This can be achieved with just clicking a few ribbon buttons. No coding nightmares. Data doesn't have to be duplicated.

Life can be simple. A lot of things that were only doable with VBA a few years ago are now doable much faster and much easier with Power Query. Use current technologies instead of outdated concepts.